# Basic question related with "Connection" of @solana/wallet-provider-react

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

```
import type { ConnectionConfig } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Connection }enter preformatted text here from '@solana/web3.js';
import type { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { ConnectionContext } from './useConnection.js';

export interface ConnectionProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
    endpoint: string;
    config?: ConnectionConfig;
}

export const ConnectionProvider: FC<ConnectionProviderProps> = ({
    children,
    endpoint,
    config = { commitment: 'confirmed' },
}) => {
    const connection = useMemo(() => new Connection(endpoint, config), [endpoint, config]);

    return <ConnectionContext.Provider value={{ connection }}>{children}</ConnectionContext.Provider>;
};
```

The source code above is from @solana/wallet-adapter-react
Mostly we will use this contextProvider on the top of the DOM tree like below.

```
<ConnectionProvider>
 <WalletProvider>
  <App/>
 </WalletProvider>
</ConnectionProvider>
```

And there comes the point that I'm wondering. What if the connection be disconnected?
Then, the defined const variable "connection" will be useful regardlessly?

Answer (score 1):

`connection` isn't a maintained connection (other than when using `websocket`)

You supply your `RPC` `url` and the `Connection` object will send `HTTP` requests when needed

If there is some issue with the `RPC` , a specific call will fail but the object is still valid